# HTML5 audio tag not playing sound for the very first of unfocused tab in chrome and safari?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

I want to play a sound in my application whenever a tab is available in browser irrespective focus. I am using HTML 5 audio tag to play the sound. But chrome and safari defer the audio playing until the user navigate or focus to the tab. The entire audio request to play sound is played at a time of tab focus. It becomes too noisy when you hear lot of sound playing at a time. Is it possible to play a sound from unfocused tab without browser defer nature? Suggest me any alternative solution available for handling this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So all you want is a audio tag to play even if you're on another tab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behavior since Chrome 46. To optimize browser performance and to conserve power, Google has disabled the auto-play on the background tabs. However starting from Chrome 47, there is a way for a person to override it by **enabling** the Chrome flag

> <strike>chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback</strike>

**UPDATE**: Chrome flag is no longer available since Chrome 60 (thank you @gordie)

There is no workaround that would allow sound to play in the 'background' tab. The solution is to not play any sounds until the page is focused. For that you can either use the `window.onfocus` event handler or, preferably, the Visibility API ([more info](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/)).

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for this information. But Soundcloud manages to do it, so there should be a workaround ?

Comment: I just tested SoundCloud on Chrome. It does not seem to autoplay. For example, if you open this link [embedded SoundCloud player] in a new tab https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/118596500&auto_play=true&buying=true&liking=true&download=true&sharing=true&show_artwork=true&show_comments=true&show_playcount=true&show_user=true&hide_related=false&visual=true&start_track=0&callback=true (Right click -> Open link in new tab), then it won't autoplay, until you focus that tab.

Comment: There are two "hacks" possible:
1) If multiple tabs are open, use the one that was focused at least once to play sounds
2) When the tab is first focused, use Audio API to play some silent clip. This way, when the time comes, you can start a playback without having to wait for the person to focus the tab.

Comment: Hi Xeos, thanks for your reply. Yes it works on Soundcloud, check eg. https://soundcloud.com/chin1993/likes - about your two hacks, can you explain a little bit more ?  Thanks !

Comment: This flag does not exists anymore (chrome 60 here)